# Why my a element tag does not effect the links? Right syntax?

Tags: html, css, navigation

Why my a element tag does not effect the links? Right syntax? I have navigation links and for some reason, the css properties does not effect my links in any way, any reason why? I also want the links to effect only inside the id #nav, no other a tags are to be effected as what I'm trying to do.

**CSS CODE:**

```
a#nav:link, a#nav:visited, a#nav:active{color:#FFB405;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;} /*doesnt work... why?*/
a#nav:hover{background-color:#FFB405;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<!--NAVIGATION-->
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="classlist.html">Class List</a></li> <!--change URL later-->
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a#nav` is incorrect. Try `#nav a`. This syntax targets an `a` that is a descendant of `#nav`. Your syntax targets an `a` with `id="nav"`

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selectors are wrong.  You have

```
a#nav:link, ...
```

but it should be

```
#nav a:link, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change css to this:

```
#nav a:link, #nav a:visited, #nav a:active{color:#FFB405;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;} /*doesnt work... why?*/
#nav a:hover{background-color:#FFB405;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WMLx7/

Answer (score 1):

You have set `a#nav` and the `nav` id is set to the parent `ul`.
Please try `ul#nav li a` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2DT/

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
a#nav:link to #nav a:link
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use this: `a#nav` it means `<a id="nav...` but you are having something like:

```
 <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

So use:

```
#nav a { // and add its properties like link, hover, active!
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have is that you are using a#nav when it should be #nav a.

## nav a references the tag with the id 'nav' and selects all the  tags.